# move Code Igniter app to new server

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to do some work on a web app that uses Code Igniter.

They've mailed me a zip file with all their content, including their application folder.  I know enough about Code Igniter to know that's important.

I've installed Code Igniter on my development laptop.

How do I verify this initial Code Igniter set up is configured properly?  I've defined my hostname as 127.0.0.1 but when I start the web server and open 127.0.0.1 I get a completely blank screen.  I thought I'd see the contents of one of the index.html files that are running around.  This IS better than a "page not found" screen - but it hints at a misconfiguration.

Also, how do I get the content (from that zip file emailed to me, the one containing an application folder) to display in my local Code Igniter installation?  Is it as simple as copying the contents of the zip file application folder to the application folder created when I installed Code Igniter?  There are all kinds of additional folders at the same level as the zip file's application folder.  Do those also need to be copied over?  Is there a way to unzip the zip file to a location in my home dir and tell Code Igniter to pick up the files from there?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the zip contain:

- index.php file
- application folder
- system folder

If so you should be able to just extract this to your htdocs, or a sub folder if you wish...

Otherwise download a new [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) installation, replacing the application folder. However you may wish to identify what version of CI the application was created in down this route so you can start off with that version (upgrading the the latest if required).

Does the zip also contain a `.htaccess`file? This may contain some rules regarding the URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit two files in order to get the configuration working on the code side:

1. In application/config/config.php, change your "base_url" to whatever URL you are using on your localhost. In your case it sounds like this would be `http://127.0.0.1/*foldername*`
2. In the .htaccess file (likely located in the top-level directory), you will have to change your base if mod_rewrite is being used.

That should get you set up on the code side of things. As for the server, make sure you have your virtualhost pointing towards the right directory if you are using Apache.